# Dynamically adding filters

Tags: php, filters, actions, array, variables

I have a function that I'm trying to get an array in it to use in a callback to dynamically add filters.

Here is the function that I need to retrieve the array keys from ( in the **$classes** variable ):

```
function bw_add_markup_class( $attr, $context ) {

    $classes = array( 
        'nav-primary'     => 'navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top',
        'nav-secondary'   => 'navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top',
        'site-header'     => 'navbar navbar-static-top'
    );
    $classes = apply_filters ('bw_custom_classes', $classes, $context, $attr);

    $value = isset( $classes[ $context ] ) ? $classes[ $context ] : array();
    if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
        $classes_array = $value;
    } else {
        $classes_array = explode( ' ', (string) $value );
    }
    $classes_array = array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $classes_array );
    $attr['class'] .= ' ' . implode( ' ', $classes_array );
    return $attr;

}
```

**Originally I was doing this to add my filters:**

```
add_filter('genesis_attr_nav-primary', 'bw_add_markup_class', 10, 2);
add_filter('genesis_attr_nav-secondary', 'bw_add_markup_class', 10, 2);
add_filter('genesis_attr_site-header', 'bw_add_markup_class', 10, 2);
```

However, I started adding more values to the $classes array and I also wanted to be able to dynamically add more through the `bw_custom_classes` and not have to write the `add_filter` for them.

So this is where I got stuck. While the below is an improvement it still doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do.

```
$classes_keys = array(
    'nav-primary',
    'nav-secondary',
    'site-header'
);
foreach($classes_keys as $context) {
    $context = "custom_attr_$context";
    add_filter($context, 'bw_add_markup_class', 10, 2);
}
```

### My best guess:

I'm hoping to be able to do something like this although my php knowledge is about maxed out right now and I'm lost.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'add_filters_to_front');
function add_filters_to_front() {     
  $filters = bw_add_markup_class();
  foreach(array_keys($filters) as $context){
    $context = "genesis_attr_$context";
    add_filter($context, 'bw_add_markup_class', 10, 2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but that last part is messy.
You are using the `bw_add_markup_class` function for two different purposes :

- to return the classes that you want to add
- to list the context of the filters that you want to call

If I understand well want you are trying to do, you need a function to return the array and then apply your modifications separately:

```
<?php
/**
 * Default array of classes to add separated from bw_add_markup_sanitize_classes()
 * This allows it to be used several places
 */
function bw_merge_genesis_attr_classes()
{
    $classes = array(
            'content-sidebar-wrap'      => 'row',
            'content'                   => 'col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1',
            'sidebar-primary'           => 'hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-lg-3',
            'archive-pagination'        => 'clearfix',
            'entry-content'             => 'clearfix',
            'entry-pagination'          => 'clearfix',
            'sidebar-secondary'         => '',
    );
    if (has_filter('bw_add_classes')) {
        $classes = apply_filters('bw_add_classes', $classes);
    }
    return $classes;
}

/**
 * Adds Filters Automatically from Array Keys
 */
add_action('genesis_meta', 'bw_add_array_filters_genesis_attr');
function bw_add_array_filters_genesis_attr()
{
    $filters = bw_merge_genesis_attr_classes();
    foreach(array_keys($filters) as $context) {
        $context = "genesis_attr_$context";
        add_filter($context, 'bw_add_markup_sanitize_classes', 10, 2);
    }
}

/**
 * Clean classes output
 */
function bw_add_markup_sanitize_classes($attr, $context)
{
    $classes = array();
    if (has_filter('bw_clean_classes_output')) {
        $classes = apply_filters('bw_clean_classes_output', $classes, $context, $attr);
    }
    $value = isset($classes[$context]) ? $classes[$context] : array();
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $classes_array = $value;
    }
    else {
        $classes_array = explode(' ', (string)$value);
    }
    $classes_array = array_map('sanitize_html_class', $classes_array);
    $attr['class'].= ' ' . implode(' ', $classes_array);
    return $attr;
}

/**
 * Adds classes array to bsg_add_markup_class() for cleaning
 */
add_filter('bw_clean_classes_output', 'bw_modify_classes_based_on_extras', 10, 3);
function bw_modify_classes_based_on_extras($classes, $context, $attr)
{
    $classes = bw_merge_genesis_attr_classes($classes);
    return $classes;
}
```

**Usage in template or elsewhere:**

Now you can add classes to the array for cleaning and they will automatically be added to filters as well...

```
add_filter('bw_add_classes', 'bw_custom_example');
function bw_custom_example($classes) {
    $new_classes = array( 
        'nav-secondary'  => 'navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top nav-blue',
        'entry'          => 'panel panel-default',
    );
    return wp_parse_args($new_classes, $classes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabien. My question really was poorly written. I didn't want to include all the code because it was a very large amount, so it didn't make much sense. However, your answer helped me figure it out along with this great [tutorial here](pippinsplugins.com/a-quick-introduction-to-using-filters/). While your answer wasn't totally what I wanted, I wanted to give you credit so I edited it.

Comment: For anyone interested [here is the complete useage](https://gist.github.com/bryanwillis/0f22c3ddb0d0b9453ad0) for Genesis themes.